Units and dimensional analysis
I was reading a paper about "Radio emissions from pulsar companions" by F. Mottez and P. Zarka (https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.1333) and stepped over equation (16) about the relativistic gyrofrequency in the observer's frame:
$$\small f_{c,o}=25\gamma\left(\frac{B_{*}}{10^5T}\right)\left(\frac{1AU}{r}\right)^2\left(\frac{R_{*}}{10^4m}\right)^2\times \left( 1+\left(\left(\frac{\pi 10^5}{\gamma}\right)\left(\frac{10ms}{T_{*}}\right)\left(\frac{r}{1AU}\right)^2\right)\right)^{1/2}\tag{16}$$
Where $B_{*}$ is the magnetic field of the star, $R_{*}$ its radius of the star, $T_{*}$ its period, $r$ the distance of the companion from the center of the star, and $\gamma$ is the Lorentz factor.
observer's frequency:
I do not understand how can you get hertz (s$^{-1}$) from all this. Also what are the authors trying to do by multiplying (or dividing) by AU, ms, and so on.

Something ses to be missing from the sentence Observers frequency:, was there an equation printed there also?

This is common notation in astronomy papers. Each ratio like $\frac{B_\star}{10^5 {\rm T}}$ is dimensionless. The symbol (like $B_\star$) should be defined somewhere in the paper, and the numerical value (like $10^5\ {\rm T}$) gives you an "expected" or "reference" numerical value for that quantity. By this, I mean: if the quantity is known precisely, it's precise value will be give; if it is known approximately, an approximate value will be given; and if it is unknown within some range, a value will be given that the authors think are "typical". In this case, it looks like the authors are giving order of magnitude estimates for each quantity.
When expressed this way, then the overall factor $25 \gamma$ gives the numerical value expected for $f_{c,o}$. To be precise, "Hertz" should be attached to the numerical value; $(25\ {\rm Hz})\times \gamma$, but sometimes people are lazy about this. (To be clear, I didn't read the paper, so I'm trusting you that $f_{c,o}$ represents a frequency). The expression also tells you how the value $25$ will scale if you change the parameters; for example, you can see that the frequency will grow linearly with $B_\star$, so you can account for the difference if $B_\star \neq 10^5\ {\rm T}$ by simply scaling the result.
In other words, this notation gives a numerical value under some numerical assumptions, shows you the assumptions explicitly, and tells you how the answer is modified if you vary some of the assumptions.

there is also clearly a choice to use convenient units, like A.U. for distances and $10^5$T for fields; isn’t 10km the “typical” size of a neutron star?

Even more fun is when you see authors write variables with the appropriate unit scale as a subscript, $X_{U}\equiv X,/,1 U$, instead of writing it out fully. Loads of fun.

Considering equation $(14)$ is possibly a good way of understanding the more complex equation you have highlighted.
An angle interval $\Delta$ corresponds to a time interval $\tau$ given by $\left(\dfrac{\rm deg}{\Delta}\right)\left(\dfrac{\tau}{\rm s}\right) = 240 \left(\dfrac{T_{\rm orb}}{\rm day}\right) \dots \dots (14)$.
On the left hand side there is a parameter $\dfrac {\tau}{\Delta}$ with units $\rm second/degree$ and this parameter is related an orbital period which is known in days, rather than in the less practical units, hours, minutes, seconds, etc.
Equation $(14)$  has a constant $240$ in it to enable one knowing the period in days to easily find the value of the parameter $\dfrac {\tau}{\Delta}$ in $\rm second/degree$.
Suppose $T_{\rm orb} = 2\,\rm days = 2 \times 24\times 60\times 60 = 172,800\,\rm second$ and one complete orbit is $360^\circ$ then $\dfrac {\tau}{\Delta}=\dfrac{172,800}{360}= 480\,\rm sec/deg$ which is the value which is obtained using equation $(14)$,
$240\times 2 = 480\,\rm sec/deg$.
You can think of the $240$ as a conversion factor.
The equation you quote is $(16)$ in the article which follows on from equation $(15)$, and constants $25$ and $\pi\,10^5$ are the conversion factors in that equation.

I must confess that in part I chose an equation from the paper which the OP did not mention because I could not apply the same steps for the "conversion factor" $25$ in the OP's equation.
The term $\left(\dfrac{\pi 10^5}{\gamma}\right)\left(\dfrac{10ms}{T_{*}}\right)\left(\dfrac{r}{1AU}\right)$ could be dealt with in the same way as above.
It comes from $\dfrac{r}{\gamma r_{\rm LC}}$ where $r$ is a distance, $\gamma$ is a dimensionless constant and $r_{\rm LC}$ is the light cylinder radius $= \dfrac {2\pi}{cT_*}$ where $c$ is the speed of light and $T_*$ is a period.
Thus $\dfrac{r}{\gamma r_{\rm LC}}= \dfrac {2\pi r}{\gamma c T_*}$ and if $r$ is in AUs and $T_*$ is in $10\,\rm ms$ the conversion factor is $\dfrac{2\cdot \pi\cdot 1.496\times 10^{11}}{3\times 10^8 \cdot 10^{-2}} \approx \pi\,10^5$.
Searching the literature I found that the authors published an erratum which corrected the originally published equation as,

